# Why are $\int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta\ \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1\pm 2 x \cos(\theta) + x^2}$ equal to the same thing?

Tags: integration, symmetry

Consider the following two integrals for $x\geq 0$:
$$
I_{\pm}(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta\ \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1\pm 2 x \cos(\theta) + x^2}
$$

These two integrals evaluate to the same thing:
$$
I_{\pm}(x) = \begin{cases}\ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \ \ \ \ , \ x\in[0,1] \\
\ \frac{\pi}{2x^2}\ \ \ , \ x \in[1,\infty) \end{cases}
$$

Do the integrals $I_{\pm}$ possess a symmetry where the fact that $I_{+} = I_{-}$ is immediately obvious? (taking $x \to -x$ or $\theta \to -\theta$ doesn't work and I am out of ideas)

Comment: Try $\theta \to \pi - \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: replace $\theta$ by $\pi-\theta$.